# Finding a class of functions such that changing one input variable will change the output in a way that depends on all inputs

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose you have a function of two input variables, $f(x, y)$. When one of these inputs is modified (e.g., $y \rightarrow z$), the function's output will change to $f(x,z)$. Lets call this difference $d = f(x,z) - f(x,y)$. I have the intuition that $d$ always depends on $x$, unless the function $f$ is linear, but I'm struggling to prove this.

This is what I have so far. If $f$ is linear, then we can write:

$$d = f(x,y) - f(x,z) = f(x-x, y-z) = f(0,y-z)$$

Thus, if $f$ is linear, $d$ is not a function of $x$ and therefore is independent from it. I would like to find a class of functions where $d$ must depend on $x$. How do I approach this?

EDIT: as @epiliam pointed out, non-linearity does not guarantee that $d$ depends on $x$. For which class of functions, then, is this guarantee met?

---

Background information:

My inspiration to prove this comes from a weird move in a modeling paper in psychology. They have a recurrent neural network model, where the value of the so-called "recurrent" layer is determined by two inputs: its previous value and an external input. When they modified the external input, the value of the recurrent layer changed, and they want to attribute this change exclusively to the input that they modified (because the other input was held "constant"). However, I suspect that the other input must have had a powerful influence on the change in the output of the function, although it was held constant.

Comment: Consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Or countless other examples of the form $g(x) + h(y)$

Comment: I'm trying to prove that this property holds for any non-linear function in general

Comment: Yes, and I have given you an example of a nonlinear function for which it doesn't hold.

Comment: My apologies. Well, this makes the problem more interesting - the property I'm looking for is not non-linearity per se. Any idea what the property might be, where the influence of $x$ always depends on $y$ and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies for all $x_1, x_2, y, z\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x_1, y)-f(x_1, z) = f(x_2, y)-f(x_2, z)$. Prove that there exist functions $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x, y)=g(y)+h(x). $$

*Proof:*

Define, for some $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, the function $g(t)=f(x_0, t)$. Therefore it holds for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ that
$$f(x, y)-f(x,z)=f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,z)=g(y)-g(z). $$
Therefore
$$f(x,y)=g(y)+f(x,z)-g(z).$$
Define $h(x)=f(x,z)-g(z)$.